# CFG for $a^ib^jc^k : j <= i + k$

Tags: formal-languages, automata, context-free-grammar, formal-grammar

I am trying to figure out the CFG of a given language.

For $a^ib^jc^k :j = i + k$

I found a solution something like below.

$$\begin{align}
S_0 &\to aS_1bS_2
\mid S_1bS_2c
\mid\epsilon \\
S_1 &\to aS_1b
\mid\epsilon\\
S_2 &\to bS_2c \mid \epsilon \\
\end{align}
$$

But when the condition is $j \le i + k$ I cannot figure out how should I modify my CFG.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a slightly simplified grammar for the equality condition:

$$\begin{align}
S&\to S_1 S_2\\
S_1&\to a S_1 b \mid \epsilon\\
S_2&\to b S_2 c \mid \epsilon
\end{align}
$$

In effect, this ensures that an $b$ is added whenever either an $a$ or a $c$ is added. For the condition $\le$ instead of $=$, we instead add *at most one* $b$ instead of exactly one time:

$$\begin{align}
S&\to S_1 S_2\\
S_1&\to a S_1 b \mid a S_1\mid\epsilon\\
S_2&\to b S_2 c \mid S_2 c\mid\epsilon
\end{align}
$$

Similarly, for the $\ge$ condition, we want to make sure that *at least one* $b$ is added:
$$\begin{align}
S&\to S_1 S_2\\
S_1&\to a S_1 b \mid S_1 b\mid\epsilon\\
S_2&\to b S_2 c \mid b S_2\mid\epsilon
\end{align}
$$

These patterns are quite useful if you're playing the "write me a CFG game". More importantly, they might provide some insight into how pushdown automata work (and why they're called pushdown automata), and even into how to think recursively.

Comment: Firstly, thanks for your answer. After your solution, I wonder one more thing. If there is no equality, like only ">" or "<", what will happen? Because equality makes it very easy to modify but what else in the other case?

Comment: @searil: good exercise :-) yes, it's a bit more work.

Comment: @Searil: if you haven't figured it out yet, look at the top-level non-recursive rule. What would you need to ensure there is at least one more $b$? Or one more $a$ or $c$?